# How to load the debug symbol when profiling Swift

Tags: swift, xcode-instruments

When I profile Swift code using the Time Profiler I am not seeing any of the symbols. See the screenshot below:

[image]

I have editing the scheme used for profiling the app, and have ensured that it uses the Debug build configuration, but this has not solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed in Xcode 6 beta 2. In the beta 2 release notes:

> Instruments will now find symbols when using Time Profiler with iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug in Xcode 6 beta 1. I have the same bug occurring with Objective C code. Make sure to open a radar for this issue over at https://bugreport.apple.com and update your question with the bug number.